# Extracting the string from URL splitting "/" Slash in SharePoint Online Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, url

I have string link `/sites/fahad/Auto/Level 1/Level 1.1` and I want to split or extract it by last slash every time.

Link in first split I want value like `Level 1.1` and in second split `Level 1`, How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you need to split it in javascript code?

Comment: @AlokKumarGupta, Can you write JavaScript in Designer workflow?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "Designer Part" earlier. I have added my take on solution below.

Answer (score 0):

We may use "Find Substring in String" and "Extract Substring from Index of String" actions in designer workflow in a loop for this. e.g.

1. declare variable current url string, last substring, current substring
2. find index of "/"
3. store current value substring to last substring
4. extract substring and store it in current substring
5. extract remaining string in current url string

Loop through till current url string is empty. At the end current substring will have final substring and last substring will have last to second substring.

Comment: not helping out

Comment: what is the difference between expected and received values or flow